# After updating android studio, and WSL I can't connect expo to emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, expo

I recently updated android studio, and WSL from WSL1 to WSL2. I tried running `expo start` which works, until I try to open the app on my emulator which is running already. Then I get this error.

[image]

Obviously there is a connectivity problem between expo and the emulator, I am just not sure what I need to do.

Anyone know if there is any new changes with the new android release, or something else I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with WSL2. After downgrading back to WSL1 I was able to connect to the android emulator.